# Putting array containing multiple arrays into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

What I have:

An array with 30 keys, some keys contain only one value, while others contain several (one key contains 28 values). So firstly I don't even know if this will work. But I have tried using other examples I've found on here only to come up null.

say like such

```
'name' => somemovie
cast => person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6
poster => poster1, poster2, poster3
year => someyear
```

and so on and so forth

My question is: Is it possible to put these in a mysql table and if so how? I'm using PHP 5.3.

This is the code I have, and the bottom half I used some years ago, for a simple array and it worked fine. Not so much anymore.

```
$imdb = new Imdb();
$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("$cat");
     extract ($movieArray);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "custom_xxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx", "custom_xxxx");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
$result = mysqli_insert_array("imdb", $movieArray);

if( $result['mysqli_error'] ) {
    echo "Query Failed: " . $result['mysqli_error'];
} else {
    echo "Query Succeeded! <br />";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}

?>
```

Comment: What application level language are you using? You could start with the following tables: movies(movie_id,year), actors(actor_id,name,dob), posters(poster_id,movie_id), and a table that relates movies to actors(movie_id,actor_id,billing).

Comment: thanks for the reply Strawberry, im using php5.3 mysqli/mysql, so you are saying to use two tables? i have this info loaded into one array, $movieInfo(), honestly i dont know how to go about even writing one key value pair.  mysql_insert_array i believe is deprecated, and Ive used that before.  pdo and prepared statements i guess are the way its done now.  all i need is an example snippet, and i can figure the rest out.  thanks for your time!

Comment: No. I'm saying use four tables. Just construct a loop to parse the array. I'm no php coder but there must be a billion examples out there - using both PDO and mysqli methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use serialize function but I would recommend against it. Create three tables with following columns which would depend on your data model but it would be something like this:

- `movies` (movie_id,year, poster_id, actor_id) - store movies here
- `actors` (actor_id, name, dob)  - stores actors info here.
- `posters` (movie_id) - store poster info here.

Now, for data entry into the database. You need to something like:

```
$imdb = new Imdb();
$movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("$cat");
     extract ($movieArray);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "custom_xxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx", "custom_xxxx");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
//the following code assumes $movieArray  like this:
// $movieArray = Array(
//'name' => somemovie,
//'cast' => array(person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6)
//'poster' => array(poster1, poster2, poster3)
//'year' => someyear)
foreach($movieArray as $row){
          foreach($row['cast'] as $name){
                    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO actor values($name['name'], $name['dob'])");
          }
          foreach($row['poster'] as $name){
           //insert into poster table 
          }

          //add foreach loop for each table.
}
if( $result['mysqli_error'] ) {
    echo "Query Failed: " . $result['mysqli_error'];
} else {
    echo "Query Succeeded! <br />";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

this is not the actually code as you haven't shown the array structure but i think you will get the idea.  basically, for multidimensional array, you need to  use `foreach` loop & inset the data into database tables using [`insert`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) statement.

For retrieval you will need to use [`SELECT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) statement. lastly, if you don't have exposure to SQL & databases, check [SQL Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp)

Comment: gaurish thank you, that makes it a whole lot easier for me to understand the hows.  thats all i needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to store the array as object and dont want to run sql queries on it than serialize the object and save it as binary mysql.

serialization: http://php.net/manual/de/arrayobject.serialize.php

mysql-binary: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/binary-varbinary.html

Comment: if i serialize can it be pulled back into the same array?  im sorry to be so dense, i dont do much sql, i mostly just save my stuff to variables and arrays and use it just then, but the execution time to grab the info everytime is about 10-15 seconds, im looking not to run the script except once to get the data.

Comment: Yes! That is the main focus of serialization: Represent the object as binary-data for saving or transfering and restoring it to the same object with the old state.